# How do I interop unlock my Windows Phone?

Tags: nokia-lumia-625

Some details about my phone:

Phone model: Nokia Lumia 625

OS: Windows Phone 8.1

Developer unlocked

I've trying to interop unlock my windows phone so that I can install Windows 10 on it. I've tried a lot of methods on the internet, but none of them seem to work for me. Any ideas how can I unlock it hassle-free?

Some methods I already tried -

Using CustomWPSystem to patch extras+info into ROMRebuilder/vcREG: The extras+info won't get installed to the SD card because Windows Store doesn't allow it to be.

Windows Insider upgrade: The preview version has been removed for other phones now!

WPInsiderHacks: Unabe to install Fiddlerroot.cer both manually (using Fiddler app) or through WPInsider Hacks! (I've triple checked WiFi proxy settings and the site for installing the certificate)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used [this guide](https://forums.windowscentral.com/windows-10-mobile-how-guides/436253-guide-installing-redstone-unsupported-devices-x2x-series.html) to install Windows 10 Mobile (Redstone build) on my Lumia 1020. You won't be able to install the vcReg on Windows Phone 8, and I'm not sure about those other methods you tried.

It's a bit involved, but if you stick with it and follow 100% it should work.

The only thing I recommend doing afterwards is to edit the registry values to spoof your phone as a 950XL so you can continue to get the regular Windows updates. (I just got the 14393.693 build this week.) For that I installed Interop Tools Beta 1.8 [from here](https://forum.xda-developers.com/windows-10-mobile/interop-tools-appx-windows-10-mobile-t3373675) in order to edit the registry right from the phone. Change the following under HKLM -> SYSTEM -> Platform -> DeviceTargetInfo:

- "PhoneModelName" to "Lumia 950 XL"
- "PhoneHardwareVariant" to "RM-1085"